# accessing the sim card contacts in android

Tags: android, contacts, sim-card

i need to access the first 10 sim card contacts on my phone. the code i used is the following:

```
public class simcontacts extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Uri uri16 = Uri.parse("content://icc/adn/");

    String[]SimContactsName = new String[250];
    String[]SimContactsNumber = new String[250];
    int count = 0;
    ContentResolver cr = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(uri16,
            null, null, null, null);


    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
    while (cur.moveToNext()) {


    String id = cur.getString(
                    cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

    if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0)
    {   
         Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
                null, 
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", 
                new String[]{id}, null);
                while (pCur.moveToNext()) 
                {
                String contact = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String number = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                SimContactsName[count]=contact;
                SimContactsNumber[count]=number;
                count++;
                } 
                pCur.close();
        }
        }
}

    TelephonyManager telMng = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    for (int i=0; i<10;i++)
    {
        Message=Message+SimContactsNumber[i]+"\n";
    }

    Toast.makeText(this, Message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

when i tested it on the phone, an htc wildfire S, i got all null values. 
i also tested it with the phone contacts uri, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, and it worked fine.
how can i access SIM contacts? is there another uri i must use?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working perfectly with the `Uri`:

```
Uri uri16 =ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
```

Make sure you have added the android permissions in the Android Manifest, like for example:
`android.permission.READ_CONTACTS` (Uses Permission).

Comment: @Luksprog  Can you please elaborate this, I'm still getting null values